# I need to get session ID before component is mounted in my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-component

I am creating a react app. I need to get session ID before component is mounted.
it means get the session_id before component loaded in app level ?
can anyone explain me is it possible?
 If so please give me suggestions to do do it? 
I am using react native starter kit 
https://github.com/mcnamee/react-native-starter-kit

Comment: How are you getting the session id ?

Comment: using  https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid